# wrong LUDecomposition - first row is the last one

Tags: factorization

I am having a huge problem with my Mathematica notebook.
I am trying to evaluate `LUDecomposition` and it keeps getting wrong - when I multiply `l` and `u`, I get my `A` matrix, but the first row is displayed as the last. I have no idea how to fix it...
[image]

My A matrix looks like this:

```
A = {{3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},   {2, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 2, 0, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0},   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2},   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4}};
```

What I do is:

```
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[A];
l = LowerTriangularize[lu, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length[p]];
u = UpperTriangularize[lu];
P = Part[IdentityMatrix[Length[p]], p];
MatrixForm /@ {P.A, P, l, u, l.u};
```

And I get:
[image]
The last one should equal my `A` matrix, but obviously it does not. It seems like the first row is the last one. Do you have any idea why? I will be very grateful for any kind of help because it is getting me really crazy.

Comment: `l.u` goes by the permutation of the rows done. So you need to consider `p` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nasser has already mentioned, you also have to take into account the permuation `p`. It is however not entirely obvious how to do that. Here an example:

```
{LU, p, c} = LUDecomposition[A];
L = LowerTriangularize[LU, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length[p]];
U = UpperTriangularize[LU];
Permute[L.U, p] == A
```

> True

Admittedly, my first idea was to use `L[[p]].U == A` (which returns `False`). So in that respect, the documentation could be a bit more specific.